# Python changing file permissions when not wanted

Tags: python

Any idea why the below Python script changes the folder permission to read only after it has been run? It runs once and deletes all the files in the folder but when it runs again it gets a Windows error 5 Access denied due to the script changing the permissions to read only on the folder. I can't see what it does this or how to avoid it? Thanks!

```
import os
import shutil

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(eg.globals.tvzip):
    for f in files:
        os.remove(os.path.join(root, f))
    for d in dirs:
        shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(root, d))

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(eg.globals.tvproc):
    for f in files:
        os.remove(os.path.join(root, f))
    for d in dirs:
        shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(root, d))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure why it's changing the folder permissions, I think it has something to do with Windows maybe.

Anyway you can change permissions before removing the files or directories

```
import stat
os.chmod(path, stat.S_IRWXU) #stat.S_IRWXU - Read, write, and execute by owner.
```

Comment: Thanks, this sounds promising, i should of said i didn't write this script. I'm a complete newbie. How would you add that line to the script above?

Answer (score 0):

The `rmtree` is removing the directories that `os.walk()` is expecting to iterate over next. So I suspect that is the problem.

You could set `topdown=False` in the `walk` call. Or you could clear the dirs array.